# Where to put .hgignore?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm wondering where to put .hgignore file; in the main repository or each programmer should have it on his cloned copy?

Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: What has this got to do with git?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You should put the file at the root of your repository.**

See :

- https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore

**It says**:

These files can be ignored by listing them in a .hgignore file in the root of the working directory. The .hgignore file must be created manually. It is typically put under version control, so that the settings **will propagate to other repositories with push and pull**.

Also another advantage is that, you might be working on multiple projects. Each having it's own set of pattern of files to ignore. For example, working on a Visual Studio project or a simple C++ project or a Python project.  **This ensures that patterns to ignore are relevant to the project.**

**How ever**, you may not want to replicate these patterns in every ignore files. In such a case Mercurial configuration file can reference a set of per-user or global ignore files.

**Example for global ignore files**

in ~/.hgrc<sup>1</sup>:

```
[ui]
ignore = ~/.hgignore
```

in ~/.hgignore:

```
syntax: glob
*.tex
*.R
```

<sup>1</sup> On Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`, `~` refers to `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows.

Comment: [Example showing how to ignore on a per-user basis using .hgrc:](http://superuser.com/a/231364)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen it anywhere but the main repository.

Answer (score 1):

How are you going to ignore the .hgignore without an .hgignore file in the repositry to ignore it ;P

Seriously.. it should probably be in the repository, since the files to be ignored are respositry-specific; a user can of course specify their own ignores additionally in a file specified in their .hgrc

Answer (score 0):

you can have a global one inside your `~/.hgrc` directory or a project specific one inside 
the project's root directory

Answer (score 0):

It belongs in the top folder of the repository. It is not meant for personal ignores but for project-wide ignores (i.e. applying for everyone). However, usually developers will add e.g. their faviourite editor's temp. files to that file - doesn't hurt anyone.

If you want to ignore something others probably do NOT want to ignore, put it in your personal ignore in ~/.hgrc.